# How to find a point inside expanded area of a region?

Tags: matrix, region, expansion

Okay so I have a map represented as a matrix, the cells in the matrix that contain the value 1 represents my area and the cells containing value 2 is a path that starts from my area and also ends there. When you reach the end of the path, aka when you got back to your area, then the area inside the path and the already existing area should be "merged" with the area, along with the path itself. In the following image is an example of such a math with a path. What would be the fastest way to achieve this?

[image: image1]

I considered using a fill algorithm but the problem is that I don't know how to find a point inside the area between cells containing values of 1 and 2 (pretty much the cells colored with red) in a very fast way. The matrix can be very big, for instance at the moment I'm working with a 330x330 matrix.

I'm open to any ideas, implementation language doesn't really matter, and it doesn't have to be a matrix, if you have a better idea for achieving this please tell me.

The following image represents what the new area should look like.

[image: image2]

edit: Still can't find anything. I've only discovered that for certain paths you can make the average of them and find a point inside. This however doesnt work for all paths..